# NOT EXISTS in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I've been working on a homework assignment for about a week now, and I have hit a wall. I am almost 100% certain I need to be using a NOT EXIST statement, but I cannot for the life of me get my head around the nesting of those statements. I'm sure I'm just making the question harder than it needs to be, but here it goes.

The 3 create table statements I wrote are as follows.

```
create table libraries (
    Libnum varchar(7) primary key,
    Libname varchar(40),
    Streetnum varchar(8),
    Streetname varchar(20),
    City varchar(20),
    State varchar(2),
    Zip varchar(5)
);

create table books (
    Booknum varchar(10) primary key,
    Btitle varchar(50),
    Pages smallint unsigned,
    Copyright Date
);
create table copies (
    Copynum varchar(12) primary key,
    price decimal(7 , 2 ),
    Purchase Date,
    Booknum varchar(10) references books (Booknum),
    Libnum varchar(10) references libraries (Libnum)
);
```

The query I'm trying to write needs to return the Libname of libraries that house a copy of every book. Any help would be much appreciated. I think i need a not exists statement for books and copies and then another for copies and libraries, but I'm totally lost.

Comment: Please put the query that you've tried too.

Comment: Ive tried all sorts of combinations and unfortunately none worked, my professor usually does stuff using NOT EXISTS for things like this so I just made an assumption that that's what he wanted here as well =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this with MySQL.  Here is one approach using subqueries:

```
select libname
from (
  select l.libname, count(distinct b.booknum) cnt, bcount.cnt bookcount
  from (
      select count(1) cnt
      from books
      ) bcount, libraries l
    inner join copies c on l.libnum = c.libnum
    inner join books b on c.booknum = b.booknum  
  group by l.libnum
) t
where t.cnt = t.bookcount
```

And perhaps a better slight variation:

```
select l.libname
from libraries l
  inner join copies c on l.libnum = c.libnum
  inner join books b on c.booknum = b.booknum  
group by l.libnum
having count(distinct b.booknum) = (
  select count(1) cnt
  from books
)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4db6f/7)

*EDIT -- I updated the above queries to use DISTINCT count in case you had multiple records in your copies table.  Hope this helps.*

Comment: I think I understand the second version better then the first, but when I try it it adds a library that doesn't have a copy of every book. I will try to fix it though. Never occurred to me to try and use an inner join and turn it all into one table.

Comment: @AndrewCooper -- if you update the SQL Fiddle with some of your "real" data, I'd be happy to look at it with you.  This query should only return libraries whose book count = count of books.  You may need to add DISTINCT to your query if you have multiple records in your copies table.  Try adding having count(distinct b.booknum) and see if that fixes your issue.  Best of luck!

Comment: I was just coming here to post that it was just missing the distinct =) thank you guys so much for pushing me in the right direction. This is seriously one of the best communities on any forum I've ever been on. Always very helpful.

Comment: @AndrewCooper -- np in the least, glad we could help!  SO is by far my favorite as well...  BTW -- consider marking the answer accepted so other users can see this worked for you.  Best of luck!